# How do I select a web element with no ID through Selenium/Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to select an element on the minehut.com webpage that has no ID. Everything I've found says to use a CSS Selector, which hasn't been working

The element I'm trying to select is:

```html
<button _ngcontent-c17 color="Primary" mat-raised-button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" style="margin-right: 10px;">
```

Code:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Initialize the driver and connect to the website
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://minehut.com/panel/login')

#Log in
driver.find_element_by_id('mat-input-0').send_keys(<Username>)
driver.find_element_by_id('mat-input-1').send_keys(<Password> + Keys.RETURN)

#Here is the css call
for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[color='Primary']"):
    print(i)

driver.close()
```

Ultimately the code will be paired with a discord bot to start/stop a minecraft server (among other server features)
This part is attempting to find the Start button, and potentially put it in a variable

fixed a syntax error

replacing driver.find_elements_by_css_selector() with driver.find_elements_by_xpath() works perfectly. The answer explains how to find the xpath of a web element
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to switch frames if there are multiple frames. If not, you can try `driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_of_element)`. In order to get the xpath, you can inspect the element and then right click on the highlighted text in the elements and click `Copy>Copy XPath`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you (Omar's comment was first, but this better explains how to do it, thank you though Omar).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to locate elements, xpath, css, id, tagNames
Here how it might look in css,  `css= button[color=‘Primary’]`
But, if there are any other button with same identifier, you might have problems.

Comment: I've tried that, it raises 'selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified'

Comment: I've added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

One potential thing you can try is selecting via the xpath, you can download a chrome extension called xpath finder, and then hover over the desired element to get the xpath, and then attempt to interact with it by doing:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path_of_the_element)
```

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector, correct your selector :

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button[color="primary"]')
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for catching that, sorry. That fixes the error, but doesn't find an element